# Why do network wide suspensions originate from per-site metas?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension

In the moderator annotation log suspensions that have been applied seem to be logged as originating from per-site-metas rather than the site themselves:

[image: annotation history]

Why is this?  Is it a mistake in the wording or just the way the script runs?

Comment: Just luck of the draw, I'd say. At least for this user. I've taken a look at some of other network wide suspensions, and all of those originated from main sites. Suspensions are queued and it depends what site the scheduler hits first...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it a mistake in the wording or just the way the script runs?

Neither.

Network-wide suspensions are triggered manually from a particular site and propagate to the rest of the network's main sites.

In this specific case, it just so happened that the user was disruptive on multiple child metas, so their child meta profile happened to be the easiest way to get to the page with the "suspend network-wide" button on it.

Comment: But I thought it's not possible to suspend child meta account, just the parent account? Or is it something else?

Comment: @ShadowWizard You're confusing accounts with profiles. A network-wide suspension suspends the *account* which has a number of *site profiles* linked up to it. It's initiated from a "network account" page (which is dev-only) and those can be easily accessed via a link from a profile on any site - the info is the same, just the styling is different. The account then signals to each main site profile linked to it that it's time for a suspension. In this case, since someone was looking at the profile on a child meta, they just hit the account page link from there and here we are.

Comment: Make sense except one thing that still puzzles me. Aren't account and profile the same thing, per site? E.g. [this is your profile page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/anna-lear), showing your account/profile here on this very site?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Huh. Never realized we overloaded the terms on the frickin' profile page. Anyway... In most cases, it's clear what someone's referring to when they say "account", but internally the distinction is fairly precise - your network account is a collection of your site profiles.  What you're looking at there is my MSE profile, with some additional information pulled from my account (such as what other sites I have profiles on).

Comment: I think I get it, thanks for clarifying!